# Inline function is not defined

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, boost-variant

Using *Variant* and *Visitor* idioms for dealing with abstract syntax tree of mathematical expression I faced linker errors `undefined reference to 'function_name'` prepended with warnings `inline function 'function_name' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]`, where `function_name` is all possible names of specializations (i.e. for `B` and for `C`) of function marked `// 1` below (header):

```
#pragma once
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

using V = boost::variant< A, B, C >;

struct visitor
{

    using result_type = void;

    result_type
    operator () (V v) const
    {
#if 1
        return boost::apply_visitor([this] (auto && x) -> result_type { return apply(std::forward< decltype(x) >(x)); }, v);
    }
#else
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }

    template< typename T >
    result_type
    operator () (T && x) const
    {
        return apply(std::forward< T >(x));
    }
#endif

private :

    result_type
    apply(A) const
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    template< typename T >
    result_type
    apply(T &&) const // 1
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

public : // !

};
```

(main.cpp):

```
#include "implementation.hpp"

#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    visitor{}(V{B{}});
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is live example: [main.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46e4975e2ba39121) and [header](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afff8bdf3e79cbef) files. If [contents of header file](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ac5fc8322f2ba9b) moved to `main.cpp`, then warning changed to `function 'function_name' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]`. But I am sure the sources of errors are exactly the same.

If I change `#if 0` to `#if 1`, then all compiles fine. Another note is: when I move `result_type operator () (V v) const` to second `public` section (marked `// !`), then all compiles fine too.

Seems lambda makes something subtle with instantiation of function template defined strictly below definition of lambda.

How to explain above behaviour and difference in behaviour of lambda version and version with `visitor &` passed to `boost::apply_visitor`?

Real-life example is [here](https://github.com/tomilov/insituc/blob/master/include/insituc/transform/evaluator/subexpressions.hpp#L32).

Comment: Not sure why you've deleted your last question... And no, I think the separation into header/source file doesn't make any difference here.

Comment: The example also compiles: 1) if we place `apply` (in a private section) above `operator()` 2) if we use g++, and use `this->apply` (for whatever reason)

Comment: @dyp But I always think, symbol is visible (except typedefs) before its definition in class scope, and, therefore, instantiated anyways.

Comment: I currently do not know what the problem is. It might be a bug in clang, it might be some weird dependent name lookup issue.

Comment: ... it also compiles if you drop the trailing return type of the lambda: `[this] (auto && x) { .. }` -- this smells like a compiler bug.